# Use same TCP port for accept and connect

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, ip-address

#### Edited after comment on proper use of SO_REUSEADDR

I want to use same port for both inbound and outbound connections in java

The purpose is to make a node in distributed environment. But in Tcp I need to use two different ports for accepting and initiating connections.

```
// accept incoming connection on one port
ServerSocket.accept()
// connect to remote, the port used will be different from the one used for accepting
Socket.connect()
```

Now the problem is:

- A starts listening on port a. B on b and C on c.
- when A connects B (Using `Socket.connect()`), A & B will keep the socket open for future message passing.
- B still doesn't know the port A is listening on because the the port from which b received the connection is different from a.
- when C connects B, B gives the socket address of A to C, But that port is a bound by a `Socket()` instance which doesn't have a `accept()` method

Of course, A can inform B about the port it is listening, but isn't there a direct way?

How can I make this test to pass?

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class DualSocketTest {
    ExecutorService service= Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    int echoServerport=8080;
    int localServerport=8090;

    @Test
    public void testConnectivity() throws IOException {
        // create a echo server on  port 8080
        startEcho();

        // create a local Server instance
        ServerSocket localServer=new ServerSocket();

        // set the reuseAddress to true
        localServer.setReuseAddress(true);

        // bind the serverSocket
        localServer.bind(new InetSocketAddress(localServerport));

        // create a socket to connect the echo server using the same port used by localServer
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        // but this will throw SocketBindException
        socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(localServerport));
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(echoServerport));

        // write hello
        socket.getOutputStream().write("Hello !".getBytes());
        byte[] result=new byte[100];

        // receive hello
        String ans=new String(result,0,socket.getInputStream().read(result));
        System.out.println("Server replied with : "+ans);

        // what was written and what was received must be same.
        assert(ans.equals("Hello !"));

    }
    // start a echo server listening on the specified port
    private void startEcho() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket echoServer=new ServerSocket(echoServerport);
        service.submit(()->{
            try {
                while(!echoServer.isClosed()) {
                    Socket socket = echoServer.accept();
                    System.out.println("connected with :" + socket.getInetAddress().toString() + ":" + socket.getPort());

                    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

                    service.submit(() -> {
                        while (socket.isConnected()) {
                            try {
                                outputStream.write(inputStream.read());
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println("The Client has closed connection.");
                    });
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Thread.yield();

    }
// Write something to the socket.
}
```

There is no such problem in when I previously used udp. The same socket supports `receive()` and `send()` method. For udp, sharing address is easy.

- when  A connects B, B would save the `socketAddress` of A,
- When C connects B, B would send the address of A to C and C would connect to A

Comment: "But A cannot accept new connections from the same socket used to communicate with B". What are you talking about. If `A` is listening on port `a`, both `B` and `C` can connect with `A` through port `a`.

Comment: @Kayaman I have edited the question. The problem is The port seen by b is different than the one A is listening on.

Comment: You seem to make this unnecessarily hard. Either use a standard port for the listening socket so you don't need to pass that information, or pass the IP/port combo to new nodes.

Comment: 'I want to use same port for both inbound and outbound connections in java.' Why?

Comment: NB Calling `setReuseAddress()` *after* you've bound the socket is pointless.

Comment: @EJP if I could use the same port for both inbound and outbound connection, when A connects B, the incoming socket address could be shared to other peers. Thus anyone who connects B could ask A's address and connect to A.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're attempting to achieve. Can you explain why you don't just have all the machines listen on the same port number? Then any machine can connect to any other machine knowing only the second machine's IP address. This is the standard TCP model: one side (the server) has a static and well-known port number, the client side obtains an ephemeral port number per connection. The well-known one on the server side allows the two sides to establish a connection. There is no reason to care what the specific client port number is.

Comment: @Gil Hamilton Yeh, using standard port will solve my issue. My use case is that each machine is a node i.e. acts as server as well as client. If  a node was to initiate a connection from the same port from which it was listening, other node could discover the port easily and pass that information to other nodes which it is already connected so that they could could discover that node. This can be made possible using a standard port model, but what if two nodes are running on same IP! I wanted to address this issue too.

Comment: One option you could do is have some simple UDP listener running which can broadcast the connection info for your main TCP server. This can also be a good place to display versioning info or other information that will aid your client in establishing a connection with the server.

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit: WON'T WORK IN JAVA

SO_REUSEADDR option shall be set on a socket before binding. I initially did my tests in Python (no access to a Java environment) and following script worked without errors on a Windows 10 system:

```
import socket

serv = socket.socket()          # set a listening socket
serv.bind(('0.0.0.0',8080))
serv.listen(5)

s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind(('0.0.0.0',8080))
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8090))
```

with another process listening on port 8090

Unfortunately, in Java `setReuseAddr` javadoc says explicitely (emphasize mine):

> Enabling SO_REUSEADDR prior to binding the socket using bind(SocketAddress) allows the socket to be bound even though **a previous connection is in a timeout state**.

For reasons I cannot guess, Java is more restrictive here. What looks even more weird, is that according to this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27685259/3545273) it used to be allowed on older JRE versions (up to  JRE 7U5)

---

Original (and wrong) post follows:

The trick is to set the SO_REUSEADDR option before binding. That means that you will need to use a parameterless constructor for both `ServerSocket` et `Socket`. More or less:

```
ServerSocket localServer = new ServerSocket();
localServer.setReuseAddress(true);
localServer.bind(InetSocketAddress(localServerport));
...      // Ok listening...

Socket socket = new Socket();
socket.setReuseAddress(true);
socket.bind(InetSocketAddress(localServerport));
socket.connect(...);
```

That way you can connect from your local listening port so that the peer will know how to reconnect after the connection will be closed.

Beware: untested...

Comment: As you haven't actually tried this, what exactly is the point of posting it?

Comment: I tested and got exception `BindException : Address already in use` on the `socket.bind()` call.

Comment: @EJP: I could test that it worked in Python, so I know that `setReuseAddress` must be called before binding. But I have currently no available Java environment. Just hoped it could help...

Comment: @Serge Ballesta Do you mean that what I am trying to achieve is possible in Python? If you could provide python code, it might be helpful.

Comment: @SunitaKhanal: Unfortunately it is a known problem in Java.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with java vs python. This use of `SO_REUSEADDR` to bind two sockets to the same (active) port this way is Windows-specific. It won't work on any other system. (And why it was implemented this way on Windows is a mystery to me. It's a dumb idea with negative security implications, and led to the need for a second flag -- `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` -- to work around it. I suspect the original Winsock implementer didn't understand the point of `SO_REUSEADDR`, which is to allow binding to a port in the `TIME_WAIT` state.)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed your test - hope that it's the way you wanted it to be. Take a look at the code here:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import org.junit.Test;

public class DualSocketTest {

    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    int echoServerport = 8080;
    int localServerport = 8080;

    @Test
    public void testConnectivity() throws IOException {
        // create a echo server on  port 8080
        startEcho();

        // create a socket to connect the echo server using the same port used by localServer
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        // but this will throw SocketBindException
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(echoServerport));

        // write hello
        socket.getOutputStream().write("Hello !".getBytes());
        socket.getOutputStream().flush();
        byte[] result = new byte[100];

        // receive hello
        String ans = new String(result, 0, socket.getInputStream().read(result));
        System.out.println("Server replied with : " + ans);

        // what was written and what was received must be same.
        assert (ans.equals("Hello !"));

    }

    // start a echo server listening on the specified port
    private void startEcho() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket echoServer = new ServerSocket(echoServerport);
        service.submit(() -> {
            try {
                while (!echoServer.isClosed()) {
                    Socket socket = echoServer.accept();
                    System.out.println("connected with :" + socket.getInetAddress().toString() + ":" + socket.getPort());

                    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                    OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();

                    service.submit(() -> {
                        while (socket.isConnected()) {
                            try {
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                int read = -1;
                                while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read);
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        System.out.println("The Client has closed connection.");
                    });
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        Thread.yield();

    }
// Write something to the socket.
}
```

Comment: Your test works fine, but It misses what I am trying to achieve. The what I am trying to do is create  connecting sockets which shares same port with a `ServerSocket`

Comment: can you tell me the reason? what's the use-case? you can achieve every kind of "node"-architecture using this code-snippet i think