# Can't reuse port with setReuseAddress(true)

Tags: java, sockets

I have Java application where after closing and starting again I can't reuse ports.

> java.net.BindException: Address already in use

This is my TCP client:

```
import Config.ConnectionConfig;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

public class TCP_Client implements Runnable
{
    private static Logger logger;
    private final int port;
    private final int bindPort;
    private final String serverIP;
    private Socket socket;
    OutputStream outStream;
    InputStream inStream;

    public TCP_Client(String configFileName,Logger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
        ConnectionConfig connectionConfig = new ConnectionConfig(configFileName);
        this.serverIP = connectionConfig.getIp();
        this.port = connectionConfig.getPort();
        this.bindPort = connectionConfig.getBoundPort();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if(connect()) disconnect();
        throw new java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException("This method needs to be overwritten in child class");
    }

    public void disconnect()
    {
        logger.info("Disconnect");
        try
        {
            if(inStream != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    inStream.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.error("Exception on instream close={}", ex);
                }
            }
            if(outStream != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    outStream.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.error("Exception on outStream close={}", ex);
                }
            }
            if(socket != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    socket.close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.error("Exception on socket close={}", ex);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Exception on stop", e);
        }
    }

    boolean connect()
    {
        try
        {
            logger.info("start connection with: " + serverIP);
            //socket = new Socket(serverIP, port, InetAddress.getByName("99.99.99.99"), boundPort);
            socket = new Socket();
            socket.setReuseAddress(true);
            socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(bindPort));
            SocketAddress serverAddress =new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), port);
            socket.connect(serverAddress);
            outStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            inStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            logger.info("connected with: " + serverIP);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.error("Exception on Client start", ex);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Error happens on this line:

```
socket.connect(serverAddress);
```

After closing the program I can see in resource monitor that port is still used, but has no PID assigned. I am sure that ports are closed, because in one of the threads where I use InputStream from the socket I get exception that socket is closed. After that thread is finished.

From what I understand OS waits (TIME_WAIT) around 2 minutes after socket is closed for all the traffic on socket to finish.

But shouldn't I be able to reuse the socket if I use `socket.setReuseAddress(true);` or would that only work if I don't close the process / program?

Comment: Why are you binding a port on the client side?

Comment: That was a request from the company that is implementing server side.

Comment: Try it without that.  See what happens.

Comment: Actually, "can" my last suggestion.  I think that the problem is that you are misconstruing the meaning of `setReuseAddress`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27685417/139985.  It won't work if the port is still in active use.  The goal of `setReuseAddress` is to deal with cases where connection *closing* is slow ... not to allow the same port to be used for multiple open / active connections.  (The latter is simply not possible.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Address reuse not working on new Java Runtime Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685259/address-reuse-not-working-on-new-java-runtime-environment)

Comment: @StephenC It works without binding port.

Is there any other way to set local port without binding? 
I saw that topic, but I can't really understand what do you mean. Because the process that was using that socket is finished and it had closed all the sockets before ending.

Comment: @pringi In that topic it is said that sockets are still opened. If I understand correctly my function "public void disconnect()" is closing sockets? So I am trying to connect to port that in TIME_WAIT and is not opened. Please correct me if I understood it wrong.

Comment: The problem is that you have already tried to bind the socket before you called `setReuseAddress()`, as the stack trace will show. Construct the `Socket` with no arguments, call `setReuseAddress()`, and then `connect()` with four arguments. But you should certainly push back against this requirement. They don't have any business requiring a fixed local port. You should be able to use any local port. Among other things it means you can only create one client connection at a time.

Comment: @user207421 Having only 1 connection at the time, is not the problem because we need only 1 connection. This is connection is between two systems in local network. I think that this requirement is because of safety. 
Problem that I described in my question only happens if you close program and try to run it before  TIME_WAIT is finished.
Also isn't my code as your solution? I am constructing empty socket and then "setReuseAddress()"?

Comment: I had added 'socket.setSoLinger(true, 2);' and now it is working like I wanted it. But i noticed that even if I changed time to more then 2 it doesn't affect time after connection diapers from resource monitor. There were some comments that it isn't safe to use 'socket.setSoLinger();' does anyone know more about that?

Comment: You don't want to mess around with SO_LINGER. You can lose data in transit that way, and cause needless errors at the peer.

Comment: @user207421 what do you think that would be solution then? Because you said that I am binding socket before setReuseAddress(), but I can't see that in my code.